# Remove a registry key when it has a random name

Tags: windows-registry, random

A product that I use has just installed on my system, without my consent, a liveupdate process that runs on my system every hour, even when I am not using that product.

I don't know what this liveupdate does. Sure, it might only be wanting to update the program, but it could be doing anything. This could actually be a virus. And even if it was legit, what is it going to do? Start downloading 200+ MB of files every hour if it finds an update? Automatically update the program in the background without my knowledge? God knows what else.

The product installer creates a key hkcu\software\liveupdate. Under that key is another key with a randomly generated name. In this case, 611dd93a9b5c578be68b17d997792402.

It then adds two run entries, one in startupapproved and one in run.

I can remove all the software, block it in the firewall and add a path rule to stop it running.

But I'd like to automate the removal completely, and that includes the registry keys. How can I retrieve the name of the randomly generated key?

"Reg query hkcu\software\liveupdate" will give me the key name, but i don't know how to extract only the last part - the random part - from the result. (via batch)

These are the keys to be removed;

```
hkcu\software\liveupdate
hkcu\software\liveupdate\611dd93a9b5c578be68b17d997792402
hkcu\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run\611dd93a9b5c578be68b17d997792402
hkcu\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\611dd93a9b5c578be68b17d997792402
```

Answer (score 1):

This would get the name of the key into a variable called KeyName:

```
for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('reg query hkcu\software\liveupdate') do set "KeyName=%%~nxa"
```

So the batch could be something like this:

```
@echo off

for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('reg query hkcu\software\liveupdate') do set "KeyName=%%~nxa"

reg delete "hkcu\software\liveupdate" /f
reg delete "hkcu\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run" /v "%KeyName%" /f
reg delete "hkcu\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "%KeyName%" /f
```

Comment: Perfect. So simple I'm embarrassed. Thanks. Slight modification though. For the run entries it would be "...\Run" /v %keyname% /f as %keyname% is a value on \Run, not a subkey. Sorry my fault in the way that I explained it.

Comment: Ok, I adjusted the answer :)